# How to display Commerce Pricing Attributes in Views?

Tags: commerce, views

We are using the [Commerce Pricing Attributes](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_pricing_attributes) module to create products with price-modifying attributes. I have set up a view to display line items with attached pricing attribute fields, but the pricing attributes are not rendering in the view display.

What is the proper procedure to display Commerce Pricing Attributes in Views?